# Most Efficient Way to Count Clicks

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql

I'm starting to run a few ads on a website, and I'm trying to decide the best way to track performance.

Specifically,

1. What's the most efficient way to count clicks? About the only way I can think of is to link the ad to another page with the ID of the ad as an argument (e.g. adserver.aspx?id=1234). The other page would then update the database and do a redirect to the advertiser's link. However, it seems inefficient to have to load a separate page for this. Are there any other options?
2. Also, it seems like I might need to know stuff like how many clicks occurred in a given week. But storing a separate database row with a date for every single click seems excessive. Has anyone else done something like this? Would it make sense to maybe create a new row for each week and increment a counter for all clicks that occurred that week?

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: "it seems inefficient to have to load a separate page for this" This sentence tells me your HTTP knowledge is not up to par.

Comment: @Josh: I would somewhat agree with Jonathan.  Why call the page, wait for the server to process it, receive an HTTP Redirect (or similar), request the new page, wait for the server to process it... ?  Basically, you're waiting for 2 roundtrips.  With JavaScript you can cut it to one roundtrip for displaying the page, then a lighter-weight AJAX call to log the click.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks for posting a comment that adds absolutely nothing to the conversation. The fact is that there is a fair amount of overhead processing an ASP.NET page request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that your first solution is the best option, in fact it is the design that most similar systems (OpenX, Google AdSense etc) employ.  Additionally it helps you better managed your banners and prevents your site leaking search engine spiders.

As for performance that is just a question of having a good design, in a typical design the redirection script will be fairly lightweight so should process requests fairly quickly.  It is worth mentioning that you could thread off the DB updates to reduce the redirect request response times.

There is of course another option:

Rather than homebrew your own banner serving scripts look into implementing OpenX instead, it is free and an extremely good piece of software.  OpenX can be found here:

http://openx.org/

and here for the open source version you can run on your own server:

http://www.openx.org/publisher/open-source-ad-server

Another option would be to implement something like Google AdSense and save yourself the hassle of finding advertisers etc.  Google also provides tools to allow you to sell banner space and then fallback to default AdSense banners if you have no active advertisers (OpenX will also do this and also support integrating AdSense (and other advertisers))

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wasn't aware there was anything free like this. I need to spend a bit of time researching this.

Comment: Looking at OpenX, it appears to basically be similar to AdSense where an ad auction determines which ads are served. It's interesting and I may look into that further, but I don't believe that is the way to make the most money. Similar case with Adsense, which I've been using for years. It works great--unless you want to make lots of money.

Comment: One other thing, if the ad links to my adserver page and does not post back, how could that prevent "leaking search engine spiders"? Do you mean to have my code look at the user-agent string or something? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in your ad proxy script you can check for the user agent and stop the search engine spider from following that link.  As an aside put nofollow on the href will give similar functionality but requires the spider to adhere to the nofollow.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with JavaScript.

Opening the page:

1. Send the ad URL to the client
2. When the user clicks the ad, use JavaScript to open the URL.  Or, simply use an anchor with `target="_blank"`.

Logging the click:

1. Either way, hook a JavaScript function to the ad click event.
2. When the user clicks the ad, use AJAX to call a web service.  The web service will then log the click.

This way the ad opens as soon as possible, then the browser asynchronously communicates with the server for logging.

The question is, what happens if the user clicks the ad, the page opens, then the web service call fails?  If you would prefer, you could call the web service first, then and only if the call succeeds, open the ad.  Probably not the best from the end user's perspective.

For you question #2: Storing each click gives you the most reporting flexibility later.  If you are set on weekly reports, why not set up a weekly process that generates the reports you need, then cleans up the data?  You could even skip cleaning up the data for now until space or speed becomes an issue.

`Would it make sense to maybe create a new row for each week and increment a counter for all clicks that occurred that week?` Probably not.  Only one process can update the counter at a time, otherwise you'll lose data.  The locking that has to occur to get the value then update it will probably significantly slow down.

Comment: ...and of course, if you use JavaScript it may not work at all in some browsers.  You may want a fallback mechanism with an extra page in this case. :)

Comment: @Nelson: I had wondered about javascript but I'm not an expert at it and didn't really know how to get from something running client-side to the database. I'll have to study your description more closely and research this a bit. And, yes, not being supported in all browsers might be an issue.

Comment: @Jonathan: By the way, I checked what Google ads do and it does look like they have an intermediary page.  I don't see any HTTP Redirect header, but they have this in the page: `<body><a href="http://example.com" id=link target=_parent></body><script>var a=parent,b=parent.google,c=location;if(a!=window&&b){if(b.r){b.r=0;document.getElementById("link").click();}}else{document.getElementById("link").click();};</script><noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com'"></noscript>`  You could easily implement something like this with an `IHttpHandler` instead of a `Page`.

Comment: @Nelson: Interesting--thanks! Also, regarding incrementing a counter for all clicks in a week, I'm not sure I was originally clear. I'm saying generate a unique number for any given week, and when I get a click, increment the value for the current ad/week or create a new row if it's a new week. I don't think that would be an issue with locking or lost data.

Comment: @Jonathan: But how would you "increment the value for the current ad/week"?  Wouldn't that be in one row?  All the ad clicks would be trying to update that single row.  Not sure on the performance implications, but I suspect there are some.

Comment: @Nelson: There'd be a second table with a FK to the Ads table. I'd compute the code for the current week and do `UPDATE AdCounter SET CtrValue = CtrValue + 1 WHERE CtrAdID = @ID AND CtrWeek = @Week`. A little more code would be needed to create the row if it doesn't already exist. This seems like standard SQL stuff. How could I increment the counter otherwise?

Comment: @Jonathan: You're right.  I was thinking along the problems you have when trying to do something like `select @id = max(id) from table; insert into table (id) values (@id)` which wouldn't apply in this case.  I think my brain skipped a beat... :)